# SQL - Correctly format CSS class using XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to format an HTML table by adding some CSS classes from a SQL Query using XML PATH syntax.

I tried to apply the answer found on: [Assign CSS class to HTML tags generated with SQL 'FOR XML'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599576/assign-css-class-to-html-tags-generated-with-sql-for-xml) but I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ; 
SET @tableHTML =   
N'<table border="0" cellpadding="4" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial">' +  
N'<tr>' + 
N'<th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Activity Date</th>' + 
N'<th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Lead</th>' + 
N'<th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Lead By</th>' +  
N'<th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Activity Title</th>' +  
N'<th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Featured On</th>' + 
CAST ( (SELECT 'trclass' as [@class],
          (SELECT StartDate as [*], 'tdclass' as [@class] FOR XML PATH('td'), type),
          (SELECT LeadGroup as [*], 'tdclass' as [@class] FOR XML PATH('td'), type),
          (SELECT LeadBy as [*], 'tdclass' as [@class] FOR XML PATH('td'), type),
          (SELECT Title as [*], 'tdclass' as [@class] FOR XML PATH('td'), type),
          (SELECT Featured as [*], 'tdclass' as [@class] FOR XML PATH('td'), type)
        FROM @Activites ORDER BY [StartDate],[LeadGroup],[LeadBy]
        FOR XML PATH('tr') , TYPE   
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +  
N'</table>';
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Activity Date</th>
        <th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Lead</th>
        <th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Lead By</th>
        <th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Activity Title</th>
        <th style="border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA">Featured</th>
    <tr>
    <tr clas="trclass">
        <td clas="tdclass">2016-01-01</td>
        <td clas="tdclass">Marketing</td>
        <td clas="tdclass">John Smith</td>
        <td clas="tdclass">Project XYZ</td>
        <td clas="tdclass">Web - Magazine</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, I'm getting the following error when executing the query:

> Attribute-centric column '@style' must not come after a
>   non-attribute-centric sibling in XML hierarchy in FOR XML PATH

What am I doing wrong? I must say I'm a little confused on how XML PATH works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error indicates that somewhere you are selecting something you want to be an attribute (the error indicates 'style') **after** you are selecting something that is not an attribute (probably one of your table headers). `FOR XML PATH` doesn't allow that, you have to select the attributes **first**. I cannot, however, see where you are selecting `@style` in your code.

I've modified your query to select the XML in the format you desire below.

```
declare @style nvarchar(50) = 'border-bottom:1px solid #7AC0DA'
declare @Activities table
(
    StartDate datetime,
    LeadGroup nvarchar(10),
    LeadBy nvarchar(20),
    Title nvarchar(50),
    Featured nvarchar(50)
)
insert @Activities values
('1/1/2016', 'Marketing', 'John Smith', 'Project XYZ', 'Web - Magazine') 

select
    '0' as '@border',
    '4' as '@cellpadding',
    'font-size:12px; font-family:Arial' as '@style',
    (
        select  (select @style as '@style', 'Activity Date' as '*' for xml path('th'), type),
                (select @style as '@style', 'Lead' as '*' for xml path('th'), type),
                (select @style as '@style', 'Lead By' as '*' for xml path('th'), type),
                (select @style as '@style', 'Activity Title' as '*' for xml path('th'), type),
                (select @style as '@style', 'Featured' as '*' for xml path('th'), type)
        for xml path('tr'), type
    ),
    (
        select 'trclass' as '@class',
               (select StartDate as '*' for xml path('td'), type),
               (select LeadGroup as '*' for xml path('td'), type),
               (select LeadBy as '*' for xml path('td'), type),
               (select Title as '*' for xml path('td'), type),
               (select Featured as '*' for xml path('td'), type)
        from @Activities
        for xml path('tr'), type
    )
for xml path('table')
```

If you would like the results of that in an nvarchar(max) variable, just select it into it.

```
declare @tableHtml nvarchar(max)
select @tableHtml = (
    //query from above
)
```

Comment: Oh... this makes it so much easier to read and it makes sens to me now. Thanks a lot!